# Is there a way to split a string in fixed width chunks in XPath?

Tags: shell, xpath, xpath-2.0, xidel

Using `xidel` I'm extracting the `//Assertion//Signature//KeyInfo//X509Certificate/text()` from a SAMLResponse, this is a X509 certificate as a long base64 string.

I want to split this string into 64 chars blocks

I tried with `tokenize()` and `replace()` but I could make those work,

It seems that `replace()` does not allow me to use newlines `\n` in the replacement string:

```
echo "$SAMLRESPONSE" | base64 -D | xidel --xpath 'replace(//Assertion//Signature//KeyInfo//X509Certificate/text(),"(.{64})","$1\n")' -
**** Processing: stdin:/// ****
Error:
err:FORX0004: Invalid replacement: $1\n after $1\n
Possible backtrace:
  $000000010203F668: perhaps TXQTermTryCatch + 222920 ? but unlikely
  $0000000102068BBE: perhaps Q{http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions}tokenize + 166350 ? but unlikely
  $000000010203FF78: Q{http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions}replace + 376
  $0000000101FF853F: TXQTermNamedFunction + 767
  $0000000101F71CE7: perhaps ? ? but unlikely

Call xidel with --trace-stack to get an actual backtrace
```

And tokenize will treat the whole match as separator, and separator are not included in the output

```
echo "$SAMLRESPONSE" | base64 -D | xidel --xpath 'tokenize(//Assertion//Signature//KeyInfo//X509Certificate/text(),"(?:.{64})")' -
**** Processing: stdin:/// ****















XACcI5tcJbgsvr+ivGPos/WrhywkROwbEBh6OTNXTnaBiiIK
```

Is there any way to do split a string in fixed width chunks in XPath?

Comment: I thought Xidel has XPath 3 (3.0 or 3.1) support as well with e.g. the `analyze-string` function where e.g. `analyze-string($s, '.{64}')` gives you the matches with the 64 character chunks wrapped into a `match` element, see https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-analyze-string for details.

Comment: Note that XPath does allow a newline to appear in a string, but it doesn't recognise `\n` as a representation of a newline - except in a regular expression (and specifically, not in a replacement string). Of course the host language in which XPath is embedded may recognize `\n` and expand it to a newline before XPath sees it, but that's very dependent on exactly where your XPath is defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first idea wasn't wrong, you just have to use the [codepoints-to-string](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-codepoints-to-string) function for generating the newline character:

```bash
printf %s "$SAMLRESPONSE" |
base64 -D |
xidel --xpath '
    let
        $cert := //Assertion//Signature//KeyInfo//X509Certificate
    return
        "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" || codepoints-to-string(10) ||
        replace( $cert, ".{1,64}", "$0" || codepoints-to-string(10) ) ||
        "-----END CERTIFICATE-----" || codepoints-to-string(10)
' -
```

<sup>**note:** I modified the regex to `.{1,64}` for making sure that the "replaced" string always ends with a linefeed</sup>

---

**ASIDE:** In the first place, you don't even need to build the full output with XPath.

```bash
{
    echo '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----'

    printf %s "$SAMLRESPONSE" |
    base64 -D |
    xidel --xpath '//Assertion//Signature//KeyInfo//X509Certificate' - |
    fold -w 64

    echo '-----END CERTIFICATE-----'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> *It seems that `replace()` does not allow me to use newlines `\n` in the replacement string:*

That's because regular expressions can't be used in the replacement string. You have to use [HTML entities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) or [`x:cps()`](https://www.benibela.de/documentation/internettools/xpath-functions.html#x-cps):

```
replace(...,"(.{1,64})","$1&#10;")
replace(...,"(.{1,64})","$1&#x0A;")
replace(...,"(.{1,64})","$1"||x:cps(10))
```

> *And tokenize will treat the whole match as separator*

https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-tokenize:

> Returns a sequence of strings constructed by splitting the input **wherever a separator is found**

You want to split the input based on a separator it doesn't have. So `tokenize()` is unsuitable. Instead, as an alternative to `replace()`, you could use Xidel's own [`x:extract()`](https://www.benibela.de/documentation/internettools/xpath-functions.html#x-extract). But above all, together with `parse-xml()` and [`x:binary-to-string()`](https://www.benibela.de/documentation/internettools/xpath-functions.html#x-binary-to-string) this can be done much simpler and all with Xidel:

```bash
$ echo "$SAMLRESPONSE" | xidel -se '
  "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----",
  binary-to-string(base64Binary($raw)) ! extract(
    parse-xml(.)//Assertion//Signature//KeyInfo//X509Certificate,
    ".{1,64}",0,"*"
  ),
  "-----END CERTIFICATE-----"
'
```

And because a newline is the default value for `--output-separator`, there's no need for `codepoints-to-string(10)` either.

Comment: @RubenLaguna The stdin-dash is only needed if your binary is older than r7880, which released almost 2 years ago. So, please update.

Comment: I'm using xidel 0.9.8, and without out the `-`  it errors with "err:FORG0001: Cannot cast "<empty/>" to base64Binary". With `-` it works. It was released on 2018-04-22 but it seems to be the last version in `brew install xidel`.

Comment: @RubenLaguna you can download a newer binary here https://nightly.link/benibela/xidel/workflows/main/master

Answer (score 1):

If you know some character that for sure does not appear in the original string (for example `$` is not a legal character in base64 or base64url) then you can combine `tokenize()` and `replace()` to achive the expected result:

```
echo "$SAMLRESPONSE" | base64 -D | xidel -s --xpath 'tokenize(replace(//Assertion//Signature//KeyInfo//X509Certificate/text(),"(.{64})","$1\$"),"\$")' -| cat <(echo "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----") - <(echo "-----END CERTIFICATE-----")
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

In the above command first you apply `replace()` to match groups of 64 characters and replace the group with itself plus a `$` at the end. Then you will use this `$` as the separator for `tokenize`.

Again this only works if you have access to some character that you know it can't appear on the original string like `$` in the base64 case.